# Microsoft Graph ExtensionError while updating a subscription through an AAD Registered App

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api

Normally, a Microsoft Graph Subscription can be updated by a **signed-in user** using a `Patch` request -

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/{id}
Content-type: application/json

{
   "expirationDateTime":"2016-11-22T18:23:45.9356913Z"
}
```

This works fine, however, I've registered an application on Azure Portal, and using it's `access token` and the same `Patch` request I get an error -

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ExtensionError",
        "message": "Operation: Update; Exception: [Status Code: Unauthorized; Reason: ]",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-01-11T07:16:51",
            "request-id": "a5854647-....-....-....-e4844c8c4a12",
            "client-request-id": "a5854647-....-....-....-e4844c8c4a12"
        }
    }
}
```

Currently the application has been assigned an API permission `User.ReadWrite.All`. I couldn't find any another permission that will help me update subscriptions on Microsoft and I don't think creating a service account is the ideal way.

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just learned something new about subscriptions. Each AAD resource has its own subscriptions isolated. Meaning I can't update a subscription which was created by a different AAD user.